# C++ enum class default value without initialization

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

What is the default value of `enum class` variable without initialization? The following code prints weird result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

struct C {
    C() {
        m_a = 1;
    }

    enum class E:bool {
        a = false,
        b = true,
    };

    int m_a;
    E m_e;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    cin >> c.m_a;
    printf("m_e: %d; compare to C::E::a: %d\n", static_cast<int>(c.m_e), c.m_e == C::E::a);
    return 0;
}
```

Build with **gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)**

```
g++ -g -o c c.cpp
# run, input 1 and get the result.
./c
1
m_e: 252; compare to C::E::a: 253
# run c, input 2 and get the result.
./c
2
m_e: 254; compare to C::E::a: 255
```

Q1: Why `m_e` is not initialized as `C::E::a` (value `false == 0`?) or `C::E::b` (value `true == 1`?)

Q2: Why dose the comparison expression `c.m_e == C::E::a` return **253/255**, but not `false` (value 0) or `true` (value 1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the default value of enum class variable without initialization?

It's indeterminate since you never initialized it. Reading from `c.m_e` will therefore make your program have *undefined behavior* and the program could show just about any value - or no value and crash (or worse).

Change `E m_e;` to

```
E m_e{};
```

and it'll be zero initialized which will mean `false` in your case.

Note: Zero initializing an `enum class` may lead to confusing results if `0` isn't actually the value of one of the defined enumerators. It'll zero initialize the `enum class`'s base type nevertheless.

Better be explicit:

```
E m_e{E::a};
```

> Q1: Why `m_e` is not initialized as `C::E::a` (value `false == 0`?) or `C::E::b` (value `true == 1`?)

Because, it's not initialized and anything may show up - or not show up at all.

> Q2: Why does the comparison expression `c.m_e == C::E::a` return `253/255`, but not `false` (value 0) or `true` (value 1)?

Again. The behavior of the program is *undefined*.

Note: In the current MSVC, when you do `cin >> c.m_a;` and later print the value of `c.m_e`, it'll show the value you entered into `c.m_a`. Strange? No, that's just one way *undefined behavior* may show up.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. Is there any C++ standard clause about `enum class` initialization?

Comment: @sfz You're welcome. I don't have the standard handy but you can read about [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) @ cppreference. Search to highlight the word _"indeterminate"_ on that page. It's not about `enum class`es specifically, but the same rules apply.